# C# Windows Form WebBrowser jquery and bootstrap

Tags: c#

I am building a Windows Form to display a web browser with a local file.

I have the webBroswer going to a local file, so far that works:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
this.webBrowser1.Navigate(Path.Combine(path, "index.html"));
```

and my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <input type="button" value="Here" class="btn btn-default" />
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have installed the NuGet package bootstrap and jquery and it does not appear to be applying to my index.html file....what am I doing wrong?

Here is my file structure, the javascript are in scripts, css files in content

I have tried this path https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js but I get a script error.

[image]

Comment: If you have a Windows Forms application why do you mention ASP.NET at all? That's  a framework for web applications only

Comment: You're right my bad, long morning so far

Comment: Where are your jQuery and Bootstrap files in relation to that local HTML file?  It's referencing from absolute paths, are those paths correct?  What's the URL being opened?

Comment: Seems that files are not found can you try putting int same path and remove the first `/`?

Comment: @user979331: I suspect those paths in the HTML elements aren't correct.  The HTML file is being opened as a file, not a URL from a server.  Try changing them to relative paths, relative to the HTML file.  For example: `<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" />`  Double-check that the file structure depicted in the Solution Explorer also matches what's actually on the file system, since the latter is likely what matters here.

Comment: @David I tried that and I got 3 errors Unable to get property 'createElement' of undefined or null reference